# Is it possible to set a dotenv variable from package.json script?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, dotenv

I am using dotenv in my project to get variables from a .env file. I would like to be able to set a value in the .env(dotenv) file from package.json when running `npm test`. Something similar to this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "set ENV=test mocha './test/**/*.spec.js'",
    "start": "node app"
  }
```

my .env file is simply this:

```
ENV = development
```

I'm using windows.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
"test": "ENV=test mocha './test/**/*.spec.js'"
```

in your npm script on Linux, and use

```
"test": "set ENV=test&&mocha './test/**/*.spec.js'"
```

on Windows.

BTW, if you need to cross platform, use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) so that your code can run on both Windows and Linux.

You can also use require.

For example, you have a `./test/test.env.js`

```js
// test/test.env.js
process.env.ENV = 'test';
```

and use `require` in your npm script like this:

```
"test": "mocha --require 'test/test.env.js' './test/**/*.spec.js'"
```

Comment: I have actually gone for your require method, it has done exactly as needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, you can pass `environment variables` through commands too.

i.e. with your scripts:-

```js
"scripts": {
    "test": "set ENV=test mocha './test/**/*.spec.js'",
    "start": "ENV=test node app.js"  //NOTICE I HAVE CHANGED THIS.
  }
```

Just by using, I don't know how to help about the test script, I don't understand that, but I believe it must be something like this

```js
"test": "ENV=test mocha './test/**/*.spec.js'"
```